# Calling Stored Procedure inserts NULL in all columns in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I am trying to call an Insert Stored Procedure in MySQL 5.5. The Stored Procedure I am using is :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SetProvince`(
IN p_Code VARCHAR(20),
IN p_Name VARCHAR(200),
IN p_CountryID INT(11),
IN p_Description TEXT,
IN p_IsActive BIT(1),
IN p_CreationDatestamp CHAR(8)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO province  
    (                     
      `Code`,               
      `Name`,               
      `CountryID`,          
      `Description`,        
      `IsActive`,           
      `CreationDatestamp`   
    )                     
    VALUES                
    (                     
      @p_Code,            
      @p_Name,            
      @p_CountryID,         
      @p_Description,     
      @p_IsActive,          
      @p_CreationDatestamp
    );


END;
```

But whenever I call a Stored Procedure as :

```
   CALL SetProvince('0003','Assam',1,'hehehehehe',1,'20130607');
```

It inserts NULL in all columns. Where I am wrong in this?

The table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE `province` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`CountryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Description` text,
`IsActive` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`CreationDatestamp` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `FK_province_country_idx` (`CountryID`),
```

CONSTRAINT `FK_province_country` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryID`) REFERENCES `country` (`ID`)     ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't put `@` before the variable names. The variables `@p_Code` and `p_Code` are two different variables.

@-variables are available for one connection's entire life so you can reach it from different procedures, triggers, normal queries and so on.

Declared variables and procedure parameters are available in that scope only.